# JIRA REST API gives HTTP error 400 with PowerShell v3

Tags: rest, powershell, jira

I'm attempting to write some PowerShell functions to interface with our Atlassian JIRA system (JIRA 5.2, download version).  Unfortunately, I've found through trial and error that the `Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't seem to work (doesn't support authentication headers), so I've written up a simple function called Invoke-JiraMethod.  I can confirm that this method works for GET requests; I've been able to use it to get Jira objects to my heart's desire.  As soon as I tried to create an issue, though, I started getting a HTTP 400 / Bad request error.

I've followed the steps [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Discovering+meta-data+for+creating+issues) to get my issue metadata, and I'm filling out all the required fields in my input object.  Could anyone help me figure out how to solve the 400 error?  I can provide more information if needed - I just didn't want to overflow the description of the question.  :)

```
Function Invoke-JiraMethod
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Low-level function that directly invokes a REST method on JIRA
    .Description
        Low-level function that directly invokes a REST method on JIRA.  This is designed for 
        internal use.
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [ValidateSet("Get","Post")] [String] $Method,
        [String] $URI,
        [String] $Username,
        [String] $Password
    )

    process
    {
        $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("${Username}:${Password}"))

        $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URI)
        $webRequest.Method = $Method.ToUpper()

        $webRequest.AuthenticationLevel = "None"
        $webRequest.Headers.Add('Authorization', "Basic $token")
        #$webRequest.Headers.Add('Authorization', $token)
        $webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true
        $webRequest.ContentType = "application/json"

        Write-Verbose "Invoking JIRA method $Method with URI $URI"
        $response = $webRequest.GetResponse()
        $requestStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
        $readStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $requestStream
        $json = $readStream.ReadToEnd()
        $readStream.Close()
        $response.Close()

        $result = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

        Write-Output $result
    }
}

Function New-JiraIssue
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 0)]
        [string] $ProjectKey,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 1)]
        [string] $IssueType,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string] $Priority = 3,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 2)]
        [string] $Summary,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 3)]
        [string] $Description,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 4)]
        [string] $Location,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   Position = 5)]
        [string] $Phone,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string] $Reporter,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [PSCredential] $Credential
    )

    process
    {
        $ProjectObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"key"=$ProjectKey}
        $IssueTypeObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"id"=$IssueType}

        if ( -not ($Reporter))
        {
            Write-Verbose "Reporter not specified; defaulting to $JiraDefaultUser"
            $Reporter = $JiraDefaultUser
        }

        $ReporterObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"name"=$Reporter}

        $fields = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            "project"=$ProjectObject;
            "summary"=$Summary;
            "description"=$Description;
            "issuetype"=$IssueTypeObject;
            "priority"=$Priority;
            "reporter"=$ReporterObject;
            "labels"="";
            $CustomFields["Location"]=$Location;
            $CustomFields["Phone"]=$Phone;
            })


        $json = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (@{"fields"=$fields}) | ConvertTo-Json

        Write-Verbose "Created JSON object:`n$json"

        # https://muwebapps.millikin.edu/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/IT-2806
        # $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $JiraURLIssue -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json -Credential $Credential

        if ($Username -or $Password)
        {
            $result = (Invoke-JiraMethod -Method Post -URI "${JiraURLIssue}" -Username $Username -Password $Password)
        } else {
            $result = (Invoke-JiraMethod -Method Post -URI "${JiraURLIssue}" -Username $JiraDefaultUser -Password $JiraDefaultPassword)
        }

        Write-Output $result
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For these kind of problems I would run Fiddler, perform the action either through the web interface (assuming it is using the same REST API) or use CURL as the examples show.  Then execute your PowerShell version and compare the raw web requests with one another.  This usually leads quickly to at least understanding what is resulting in the bad request error.

Comment: Better yet try [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) it is much more advanced than Fiddler. You will also be able to resend requests and modify everything. And yes, as @Keith Hill suggested, it is a very good idea to use a HTTP Proxy for this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a timing thing (since I'm a year late to this question), but why did you have to create your own function? `Invoke-RestMethod` and `Invoke-WebRequest` both handle headers easily. You just need to create an object like so: `$user = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("username:password")` `$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($user)}` and plug that into your request: `$response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post`. That isn't what you've asked, so this is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the error 400 because the issue type id number I had put into the json data wasn't mapped to anything.  fiddler helped me diagnose that.

I used this bit of code to figure out authenticating to jira via invoke-restmethod's -Headers option:  http://poshcode.org/3461

then I put the json data into a here string, and ran invoke-restmethod.

code bits below.  replace "any valid... type id number" with actual project and issue type ids you get from your jira admin.

```
$uri = "$BaseURI/rest/api/2/issue" 


    $jsonString = @'
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "id": "any valid project id number"
       },
       "summary": "No REST for the Wicked.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using ids for projects and issue types using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "id": "any valid issue type id number"
       }
   }
}  
'@  


        $headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader $Credentials

        Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Headers $headers  -Method Post -Body $jsonString -ContentType "application/json"
```